# How to send variables to php file with jquery/ajax and then echo the php to index (no alert)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm a newbie around here and I've run into a dead end.

So I've created a function to draw a calendar in php. And I've been using css to set the colors of days and that stuff. The function runs well and uses 2 input variables like this:

PHP file (calendar.php):

```
<?php
function draw_calendar($month,$year)
{
// the code
}
echo draw_calendar($current_month,$current_year);
?>
```

What I've been trying to do is use jquery/ajax (from my index file) to post/get variables to calendar.php for $current_month and $current_year to use. And then echo the function to my index somehow. For the life of my I can't manage to do that. I could only find how to return simple strings and alert them to my index.

Comment: Please show us your jquery ajax attempt so we can debug it.

Comment: Also please describe what the response from `draw_calendar()` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you have written up, but her is the general idea of how you can use ajax to send over your needed variables.

**On your index file:**

```
var month = "11"; //your month
var year = "2019"; //your year

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "calendar.php",
  data: {month: month, year: year},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
    //if it is success
  },
  error: function(){
    //if it results in error
  }
});
```

**On your calendar file:**

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
```

Comment: ...don't forget that the response from PHP now needs to be json encoded (since you have `dataType: "json"`)

Comment: Yeah indeed. `echo json_encode()` I am assuming they knows that...

Comment: There's a lot of people that are new to PHP, and web development in general, that does not know this. When you write an answer, remember that you write it for future visitors just as much as for the OP. :-)

Comment: This sends the variables to calendar.php. But I can't get the function from inside calendar.php to echo to index afterwards

Comment: Use `echo json_encode(yourData);` and then access it from the ajax function using the `response`.